# Simple python solution to check multiple if string in string set dict value

Tags: python

I want to check if a phrase is in a string of text, and if so then sent a dictionary value to 1, then repeat for three more phrases.  My code works, but I'm sure there's a shorter solution but can't seem to find one.

```
    self.results['p1_txt'] = self.results['p2_txt'] = self.results['p2b_txt'] = self.results['p3_txt'] = 0

    if "phase_1" in self.results['text']:
        self.results['p1_txt'] = 1

    if "phase_2" in self.results['text']:
        self.results['p2_txt'] = 1

    if "phase_2b" in self.results['text']:
        self.results['p2b_txt'] = 1

    if "phase_3" in self.results['text']:
        self.results['p3_txt'] = 1
```

Comment: Depending on what you're doing with this code... it might make more sense to use `True` and `False` instead of `1`, or just build a `set` of phrases that occur.

Comment: I'm creating features from text and storing them in a database for some NLP analysis.  I considered using T/F, but preferred binary thinking it may help down the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use loop

```
for item in [1,2,'2b',3]:
    if "phase_{}".format(item) in self.results['text']:
        self.results['p{}_txt'.format(item)] = 1
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of using curly brackets and forrmat() to add text, thanks for the solution and teaching me something new.

Answer (score 2):

The solution using regular `for` loop:

```
for i in ["1","2","2b","3"]:
    if ("phrase_" + i in self.results['text']):
        self.results['p' + i + '_txt'] = 1
```